# How to make a branch the new master w/o using merge?

Tags: git

I've seen other posts on how to make a branch the new `master`, but I've done what those say to no avail. Or maybe there's a way to do this with merge that I don't know.

Somehow I really messed things up. I tried to take work from tag `v0.4` and make changes till it worked and I created a new tag of `v0.6`. This is a branch called `new-stuff` and it works.

I've already tried to merge branch `new-stuff` into `master`, but after doing so, running the code does not work, somehow `new-stuff` is different even though the merge from `new-stuff` to `master` says all up-to-date.

Here's what I have and I need to make branch `new-stuff` the new `master` because now `master` does not work, but `new-stuff` does. I've shortened a lot of descriptions for brevity.

```
$ git log --oneline --graph
* 94e0390 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Updates.
*   8f36445 Resolving.
|\  
| * 4997e4e (origin/new-stuff, new-stuff) Updates.
| * 69391be (tag: v0.6) Fixes.
* | cfc420f Resolving.
* | fc18857 Resolving.
* | 877d227 (tag: v0.5, origin/working) Updates.
* | a2b0fb2 Minor fixes.
* | f2004e2 More fixes.
* | 4b1b88e Fixes.
* | cfbaa3c Fixes.
* | 9149f73 Fixes.
* | 5c2b02c Fixes.
* | 399d5b0 Fixes.
* | d613c92 Fixes.
|/  
* e3ea999 (tag: v0.4) Work.
* 261cd54 Work.
* a4fcf02 Import.
```

Comment: why not rename the branches? master is just like every other branch

Comment: I renamed `master` to `old-master` and renamed `new-stuff` to `master`, then got `error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.myco.com:me/my-proj.git'`. Then did a `git pull` but says `already up to date.`

Comment: Looks like `git push origin HEAD:new-stuff` works though. Thanks. Make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to shuffle the chairs on the deck. Git branches (including `master`) are nothing really special. You can just rename them and push them as you need to.